# order of growth of cost of weighted quick-union

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading Algorrithms 4th edition. And I'm wonder why each operation does at most a constant number of array accesses for each node? How do we get this conclusion? And why we can know from it that the worst order of growth of the cost of find() is log N?

And here are the words from the book:

> Corollary: For weighted quick-union with N sites, the worst-case order of growth of the cost of find(), connected(), and union() is log N.
>
> Proof: Each operation does at most a constant number of array accesses for each node on the path from a node to a root in the forest.”

I can understand that the depth of the node is most logN, but I can't understand why each operation does at most a constant number of array accesses for each node.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question further? Apart from the last part, the whole question is sort of unclear.